# Can you increase confidence from two similar predictions based on independent data

Tags: probability, prediction, model-averaging

Let's say I have two models to predict the out come of a game.

Model A uses the player specific statistics (speed, reaction times etc.) and predicts a 75% chance of a win for my team.

Model B uses the team statistics (recent performance, historical performance against the other team etc.) and predicts a 75% chance of a win for my team.

Can I combine these two predictions and be more than 75% confident that my team will win? My gut tells me No, but there's more to this.

If I ask a friend if they think I'm making a good bet (for example) and they agree then it'll make me more comfortable with the bet. If I ask 1000 friends, then I'll be significantly more happy that I've made the right call (if they all agree). That makes me think that, intuitively at least, my prediction confidence increases the more predictions I get (independent predictions ofcourse).

Another way of looking at this is that each model only has access to a subset of the variables. If I trained my model with all the variables it should be a better predictor (assuming enough dataset).

So what's the deal? Can I combine the models predictions? If so how? Is there an equation or methodology I can use?

Comment: Given that data used from Model A and B are different (data for Model B is not an aggregate statistic from Model A), model that uses both variables, with right feature and model selection via cross-validation will almost always outperform your model A and B. Also, you somewhat are referring to ensemble method, which you should look into.

Comment: @won782 thanks for the comment. I'm glad you agree that a model with access to all variable will out perform two separate models, is there a reliable way to combine the results of the 2 models such that I would get the result of a single model with all variables? I think this is what the ensemble method is, but so far I've not got a good grasp of it - any suggested reading?

Comment: Depends on the model; if regression is being used, you can try nested model with random effects.

Comment: https://blog.statsbot.co/ensemble-learning-d1dcd548e936 is a great viz / resource for ensemble methods.